# Mysql subquery doesn't recognize a field from the parent query

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a query with a subquery inside another subquery. So, the bottom level subquery does not recognize a field in the top level subquery.
How could I workaround it?

```
SELECT codigo, descricao 
FROM statusplano sp, previsao pr
WHERE sp.codigo = pr.status
AND pr.plano = 13
AND sp.codigo = (SELECT codigo FROM statusplano sp1 WHERE ordem = (SELECT max(sp2.ordem) FROM statusplano sp2 WHERE sp2.codigo = pr.codigo AND pr.dataPrevista <= now()))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i see an "ordem" without table alias before

Comment: I tried to rewrite this query with only one subquery, but I get the same error. `SELECT codigo, descricao FROM statusplano sp, previsao pr WHERE sp.codigo = pr.status AND pr.plano = 13 AND sp.ordem = (SELECT max(sp2.ordem) FROM statusplano sp2 WHERE sp2.codigo = pr.codigo AND pr.dataPrevista <= now())`. The error I get is "Unknown column 'pr.codigo' in 'where clause'".

Comment: can you post the tables structure?

Comment: i Think `codigo` column is in `statusplano` table

Comment: Thanks kappa for your question, I was making a mistake, the field I should link in pr talbe was "satatus", instead of "codigo". Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
codigo,
descricao
FROM sp2,
previsao pr
WHERE sp.codigo = pr.status
AND pr.plano = 13
AND sp.codigo = (SELECT
                   codigo
                 FROM sp2
                 WHERE ordem = (SELECT
                                  max(sp2.ordem)
                                FROM statusplano sp2
                                WHERE sp2.codigo = pr.codigo
                                    AND pr.dataPrevista <= now()))
```